# Can I override an interface property?

Tags: vb.net, properties, interface, overriding, implementation

Shell example is below.  Basically, I want a client and employee to implement the SSN property from IPerson.  However, I want client to have get and set (which isn't an issue), but I want employee to have get only.

```
Public Interface IPerson
    Property SSN As String
End Interface

Public Class Client
    Implements IPerson
    Public Property SSN As String Implements AELName.IPerson.SSN
        Get
            Return _SSN
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _SSN = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Employee
    Implements IPerson
    Public Readonly Property SSN As String Implements AELName.IPerson.SSN
        Get
            Return _SSN
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Employee generates an error of "'SSN' cannot implement 'SSN' because there is not matching property on interface 'IPerson'".  Is there a somewhat simple way to override the SSN implementation for Employee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement an empty `Set` - one that doesn't update anything.

```
Public Class Employee
    Implements IPerson
    Public Readonly Property SSN As String Implements AELName.IPerson.SSN
        Get
            Return _SSN
        End Get
        Set
            ' Make read only for Employee
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I'll try this out when I get back to it, but won't anything using the Employee class still have write access to SSN, it just won't set anything behind the scenes?  I was hoping it would raise an error if any future developer would try and set an SSN on an employee.

Comment: @Curtis - Yes, this will fail silently. But you can throw an exception instead.

Comment: Excellent solution to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest splitting the interface into IReadablePerson and IReadWritePerson, with the latter inheriting the former.  Note that the former interface is not `IImmutablePerson`, since the latter name would imply to consumers of the class that they should not expect any of its properties ever to change; an object which implements `IReadWritePerson` would not abide such expectation, but would abide the expectation that the person should be readable.

One slight annoyance with splitting the interface is that it will be necessary for the `IReadWritePerson` to include the modifier `Shadows` in the declarations of its read/write properties, and implementers of `IReadWritePerson` will have to provide both a read-only implementation of `IReadablePerson` and a read-write implementation of `IReadWritePerson`.  In C#, a public implementation of a read-write property can automatically generate implementations for any like-named read-only, write-only, or read-write properties which are part of any interfaces the class implements, but when explicitly declaring which interface is being implemented, the style of the interface (read-only, write-only, read-write) must precisely match that of the implementation.  Annoying.

The annoyance is made worse by the fact that one cannot simply declare `IReadableFoo` with a read-only property, `IWriteOnlyFoo` with a write-only property, and have `IReadWriteFoo` simply inherit both.  If an interface implements a read-only property and a write-only property with the same name, neither property will be usable because the compiler will announce that in statements like `somevariable = object.someProperty` or `someObject.someProperty = someVariable`, it's "ambiguous" which implementation to use.  Not that I can see any ambiguity--I can't see how the first could use anything but a getter, or the latter anything but a setter, but the compiler can't resolve it.

Comment: @Curtis: Thanks.  I added a couple more paragraphs for your perusal.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question "Can I override an interface property" ... Absolutely. Here's an example of how to do so. You simply add the **Overridable** keyword to your base concrete implementation. I know that doesn't solve changing the property to ReadOnly, but I figured I'd point out that overriding a base classes concrete implementation of an interface is possible.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim iEntity As IEntity = New MyEntity

        iEntity.SetMessage(iEntity)

        Console.WriteLine(iEntity.Message)

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module

Public Interface IEntity

    Property Message As String

    Sub SetMessage(entity As IEntity)

End Interface


Public Class MyEntity
    Inherits BaseEntity

    Public Overrides Property Message As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0}.. and overroad.", MyBase.Message)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.Message = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub SetMessage(entity As IEntity)

        Me.Message = "I was set from MyEntity."

    End Sub

End Class


Public Class BaseEntity
    Implements IEntity

    Public Overridable Property Message As String Implements IEntity.Message

    Public Overridable Sub SetMessage(entity As IEntity) Implements IEntity.SetMessage
        Me.Message = "I was set from BaseEntity."
    End Sub

End Class
```